# attempted to open sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Code but jar is properly signed

Tags: java, code-signing, java-web-start

I am encountering a very strange behaviour with a Java Web Start application.

On one particular machine (windows 7 64 bits, java SE Runtime ENvironment (build 1.7.0-b147)), the application refuses to start with the following error:

`attempted to open sandboxed jar https://example.com/jnlp/lib/LHC.jar as Trusted-Code`

The doc suggests that this particular jar contains "untrusted components". I don't know what untrusted components are but after some search it seems to indicate this is linked to particular classes or resources not signed inside the jar.

This can't be the case as I get this result with the jarsigner utility:

```
s       6501 Fri Jun 02 11:12:50 CEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        6359 Fri Jun 02 11:12:50 CEST 2017 META-INF/COMPANYBE.SF
        4115 Fri Jun 02 11:12:50 CEST 2017 META-INF/COMPANYBE.RSA
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.companygroup/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.companygroup/TestConnector/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 conf/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 Elevation/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/gui/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/exception/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/actions/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/actions/list/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 JNLP-INF/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 images/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7/
        0 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 modules/
sm     14850 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.companygroup/TestConnector/pom.xml
sm       119 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/com.companygroup/TestConnector/pom.properties
sm     19759 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 conf/axis2.xml
sm      1108 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 Elevation/elevate.cmd
sm      4023 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 Elevation/elevate.vbs
sm      1565 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/LHCSeries_Instance.class
sm       452 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/RefStatus.class
sm      2259 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/RefStatus$Status.class
sm      6239 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/LHCSeries_Transfer.class
sm      1880 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/entity/TransferType.class
sm      2367 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/gui/JWSTrayIcon.class
sm       916 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/gui/JWSTrayIcon$1.class
sm       870 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/exception/SystemTrayUnsupportedException.class
sm      1404 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/HttpServer$DefaultTempFileManagerFactory.class
sm      3633 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/HttpServer$ClientHandler.class
sm     10900 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/HttpServer.class
sm      1715 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/HttpServer$MimeType.class
sm       263 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/server/http/HttpServer$1.class
sm      1506 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/actions/list/ListFiles$1.class
sm     15039 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/actions/list/ListFiles.class
sm      3100 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/ServiceMessageContainer.class
sm       652 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/ServiceMessage.class
sm      1739 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/TransferProgressUpdateMessage.class
sm     17313 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/Main.class
sm       742 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/main/Main$1.class
sm      1922 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/CompanyThreadManager.class
sm     21190 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/LHCSeries_TransferThread.class
sm      3101 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/LHCSeries_TransferThread$1.class
sm       862 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/LHCSeries_TransferThread$2.class
sm     14261 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/thread/JobUpdaterThread.class
sm      6683 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil.class
sm      2612 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil$MyBZ2CreateCallback.class
sm      2343 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil$MyExtractCallback.class
sm      5733 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/CompanyConfiguration.class
sm      2071 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil$MyBZ2TARExtractCallback.class
sm      2328 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil$MyBZ2TARExtractCallback$1.class
sm      2796 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 com/companygroup/companyclient/util/SevenZipUtil$MyExtractCallback$1.class
sm      3864 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 STAR_companygroup_com2.jks
sm      3128 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 keystore.jks
sm      5413 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.jnlp
sm      1804 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 truststore.jks
sm       636 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 images/bulb.gif
sm      1656 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 log4j.properties
sm      3023 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/US_export_policy.jar
sm      3035 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/local_policy.jar
sm      2487 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7/US_export_policy.jar
sm      2500 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 unlimitedJCE/UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7/local_policy.jar
sm      4149 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 STAR_companygroup_com2.pkcs12
sm      9657 Fri Jun 02 11:12:02 CEST 2017 modules/rampart-1.6.2.mar
```

If I remove the Trusted-Only: true in the manifest.MF of my jars, I get the following error:

`java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar https://example.com/jnlp/lib/bcprov-jdk15on.jar as a Trusted-Library`

on the bouncycastle provider re-signed with my certificate.

This jar is also correctly signed according to the jarsigner.

I am at loss and have no idea how to move forward from here.

Answer (score -1):

There are similar issues faced by users. Please refer

[Some users gets Security Exception: Attempted to to open a sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142230/some-users-gets-security-exception-attempted-to-to-open-a-sandboxed-jar-as-a-tr)

[Security Exception: Attempted to to open a sandboxed jar as a Trusted-Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044624/security-exception-attempted-to-to-open-a-sandboxed-jar-as-a-trusted-library)

Comment: Sorry but I read those answer (of course...) and they were of no help. The first one suggests that the code of the user is not signed which is (as stated in my post) not my case at all. And the second one as well...